# How to access the colors properties after creating a colors.xml file in android studio using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I created under res ad new folder name color:

[image: color folder]

then inside color folder I created the file colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<resources>
    <color android:name="default_screen_bg" tools:ignore="ExtraText">#f9f9f9</color>
    <color android:name="rounded_container_bg">#222222</color>
    <color android:name="rounded_container_border">#3b3f44</color>
    <color android:name="light_gray_header_color">#646663</color>
</resources>
</selector>
```

then in another xml file under res/drawable I'm trying to access the colors.xml properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inset android:insetLeft="1.0px" android:insetRight="1.0px" android:insetTop="0.0px" android:insetBottom="1.0px"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape>
                <gradient android:startColor="@color/rounded_container_bg" android:endColor="@color/rounded_container_bg" android:angle="270.0" />
                <corners android:radius="11.0dip" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <stroke android:width="1.0px" android:color="@color/rounded_container_border" />
                <gradient android:startColor="@color/colors/rounded_container_bg" android:endColor="@color/rounded_container_bg" android:angle="270.0" />
                <corners android:radius="10.0dip" />

            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</inset>
```

but I'm getting red on the lines of @color/colors:

[image: color errors]

not sure how to resolve it.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial and got stuck with the colors.xml

https://javatechig.com/android/android-seekbar-example/

The main activity code:

```
package com.example.flashlight

import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var flashLightStatus: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        startFlashLight()
    }

    private fun openFlashLight() {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (!flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }

    private fun closeFlashLight()
    {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }

    fun startFlashLight() {

        var flashLightOn = false

        openFlashLight()
        flashLightOn = true

        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.postDelayed(object: Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (flashLightOn) {
                    closeFlashLight()
                } else {
                    openFlashLight()
                }

                // Changing the toggle and calling the same Runnable again after 5 seconds
                flashLightOn = !flashLightOn
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
            }
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your **colors.xml** should be under: **main/res/values/colors.xml** and remove the <selector> tag from the colors.xml file. Then use "@color/default_screen_bg"

Comment: @gioravered working.  and last, where is the public class SeekbarActivity extends Activity or where should I create it?

Comment: Add your Activity class code so I can help

Comment: @gioravered what I did before is that the flashlight on my phone will open wait 5 seconds then close then 5 seconds open and so on nonstop.  now I want to add the seek bar to control the speed of the flashlight flash in seconds.  for example, if the seek bar is on 1 the flashlight on the phone will turn on/off every second and if the seek bar value is on 31 then the flashlight on the phone will turn on/off every 31 seconds.

Comment: In this case open another question (or better.. search for a previously asked question) about Android SeekBar...